# What does a return statement with void achieve?

Tags: javascript

I am reversing a minified game from the web archive into typescript. I have the following function.

```js
const C = (command: KnownMovementKeySet) => {
  if (
    3 == game.myType &&
    ("STRAFELEFT" === command || "STRAFERIGHT" === command)
  ) {
    return C("SPECIAL"), void C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT");
  }
  if (-1 !== x.indexOf(command)) {
    Network.sendKey(command, true);
  }
};
```

What is the return statement doing here?  It would seem on first glance to be irrelevant. However, the recursive nature makes me believe I am seeing some archaic logic that I haven't seen before.

Comment: Well, the `return` exits the function within the `if` statement; it’s a conditional return, so it’s not unnecessary. The code inside the `if` statement seems to be equivalent to `C("SPECIAL"); C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT"); return;`, unless I’m missing something about the recursion semantics. Not sure why someone would write it in such a cryptic way.

Comment: Note that you should never write this yourself, of course =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void <someExpression>` evaluates to `undefined`, and the comma operator evaluates left-to-right and comes out to the value of the final expression. So

```
return C("SPECIAL"), void C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT");
```

is equivalent to

```
C("SPECIAL");
return void C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT");
```

```
C("SPECIAL");
C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT");
return undefined;
```

```
C("SPECIAL");
C("STRAFELEFT" === command ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT");
return;
```